# Dynamic categories criteria with matching products rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I'm working on a new rails project, and in this project I have products and product categories.

So these categories are very different from each other, to name some, Boats, Houses, Cars.

The car category might have criterias like "Mph", "Model", "Brand", "Year" and so on. Where the house category will have something like "Rooms", "Year", "City", "Postal Code" etc.

I would like this to be very dynamic, so that i would be able to add/remove criterias and add/remove categories from a backend panel.

Now to my question, i have been playing around with this, and i can't really figure out the logic of this concept, i have tried some solutions, however they are very weird and quite inefficient. Maybe some hardcore rails coder could give me a hint, on how to solve this puzzle?

So the best solution i could come up with, was this:

Four models :

```
 _______________________
| Product.rb            |
 -----------------------
| id          | integer |
 -----------------------
| category_id | integer |
 -----------------------
| Title       | string  |
 -----------------------
| Description | text    |
 -----------------------
```

---

```
 _______________________
| Category.rb           |
 -----------------------
| id          | integer |
 -----------------------
| Title       | string  |
 -----------------------
| Description | text    |
 -----------------------
```

---

```
 _______________________
| Criteria.rb           |
 -----------------------
| id          | integer |
 -----------------------
| category_id | integer |
 -----------------------
| Name        | string  |
 -----------------------
| Default     | string  |
 -----------------------
| Description | text    |
 -----------------------
```

---

```
 _______________________
| ProductInfo.rb        |
 -----------------------
| id          | integer |
 -----------------------
| product_id  | integer |
 -----------------------
| Name        | string  |
 -----------------------
| Value       | text    |
 -----------------------
```

How it's connected :

```
Criteria.rb is connected to Category.rb with a category_id and has_many/belongs_to relation
Product.rb is connected to Category.rb with a category_id and has_many/belongs_to relation
ProductInfo.rb is connected to Product.rb with a product_id and has_many/belongs_to relation.
Category.rb is the heart og this solution. The category model, both have many products and criterias.
```

How it should work, in reality :

```
In the show category page, i would first print out all the criterias for the given category.
Afterwards i would make a @products.each do |product|.
In the @products.each block, i would make a @category.criterias.each do |criteria|.
In the @category.criterias.each block, i would then run something like product.productinfos.where(:name => criteria.name). 
And then run it one by one.
```

Conclusion, this solution do work, however i doubt that it is the best solution. It will make an extremely big loadtime, with high traffic and many data. And i will need to write very weird and unreadable code.

This is a rather long question, and it might be very confusing, so if there is anything please just say. Also, i have searched quite alot for a question like this, both on Stackoverflow, and on google but i have not been able to find anything like this.

Oluf Nielsen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it's better not to define additional tables to handle this due lots of performance issues. My preference to handle such things is to use a serialized column in the products table. Ability to search directly in the database is reduced with this approach, but then you wouldn't want to do that anyway. To handle search, you have to add some sort of indexed searching mechanism. Like acts_as_ferret or even Solr or ElasticSearch.

If you are using postgres check out https://github.com/softa/activerecord-postgres-hstore

For Mysql, use the rails's built in 'store'
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  store :settings
end
```

To set criteria for each category do something similar to this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products


  def criteria
     @criteria_list ||= self[:criteria].split('|')
     @criteria_list
  end

  def criteria=(names)
    self[:criteria] = names.join('|')
  end

end
```

Everytime a product is added to a category, check if all of the criteria in that category is available in the product's properties hash keys. If not, add it with a default value if needed.

You can also setup accessors for the properties hash store using a proc that dynamically gets the accessor names from the all the criteria field of the categories of the product? (not sure about this, cause I haven't done this before)

You can also look into using STI (Single table Inheritance) using a type field in your products table. (It's well documented) This approach is slightly better 'cause when products move from one category to another, the properties won't change.

```
class Gadget < Product
   store_accessor :manufacturer, :model
end

class Phone < Gadget
   store_accessor :os, :touch_screen, :is_smart
end
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Or else, second approach would be go with a nosql database. Try mogodb with mongoid, which is quite stable. This will suite your requirements for variable attributes very well. Also you can add any other categories later with very ease.

As far as I can see, with mysql, you will end up creating multiple dbs for storing this dynamics data and that is bound hamper the performance.

UPDATE -

Apart from the point that your data can be flexible with nosql, there are many things you need to consider before shifting there. I just suggested based on fact that you need flexible database structure. Start with mogodb docs, they are good starting point.